# HOw to check range in alloy language?

Tags: alloy-ui

I have to generate an als script that will check the range like 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what the ultimate goal is, but a good start would be to write a signature for the structure of the IP address with abstract values for the IP components and then just declare an ordering.